# Loop invariant vs Assertions

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode, loops, invariants

I have an exam on Programming Concepts this Saturday and I am struggling to find some information to understand some concepts better.

What is the difference between loop invariant and assertion? To me they look the same.

Also, what exactly is `while` loop invariance theorem?

Not sure whether it is me or it is ridiculously hard to find any specific information about algorithms and pseudocode online.

Answer (score 8):

An [invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_%28computer_science%29) is a condition that can be relied upon to be true during execution of a program. For example, a loop invariant is a condition that is true at the beginning and end of every execution of a loop.

An [assertion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertion_%28computing%29) is a predicate (a true–false statement) placed in a program to indicate that the developer thinks that the predicate is always true at that place.  Programmers often use assertions in their code to make invariants explicit.

**[While Loop Invariance Theorem](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~bmk/se211lectures/LECTURE8.PDF)**
Assume that S is an invariant of the loop

```
While C do
 E
```

Assume also that S is true on the first entry to the loop. Then S stays true after every iteration
of the loop. In particular,

1. If the loop terminates then S is true after the last iteration.
2. If the loop does not terminate then S always stays true.